# How do I migrate emails from Outlook on a Mac into Google Apps for Business

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, migration, google-workspace

I am migrating across from an email server called IceWarp (i.e. not exchange) to Google Apps for Business. I've found that for the Windows PCs in the business I can use Google Apps Sync for Microsoft Outlook, but we also have some MacBooks that are running Outlook 2004, which is not supported by Google Apps Sync for Microsoft Outlook.

I know that I could probably use some roundabout way like copying the PST files onto a Windows PC, settings up Outlook and going from there, but is there a nice, direct way - or at least something less bad than what I have proposed - to get emails from Outlook on a Mac into Google Apps for Business.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach I have seen suggested so far, detailed at http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/kK71S-frNUs, is merely to connect the Google account to Outlook using IMAP, then copy all the content across in Outlook, which should result in all the emails being copied across as well.

Not sure how well it will work, or how to do contact and calendar data as well, but I'll give it a go unless there's a better option.